# Post to a Chatter Group from a Process not success

Tags: process-builder, approval-process, chatter-groups

I have a approval process. Through that i am updating the approval status to Approved. after the status changed to approved through the approval process I need to post chatter message to one of the private chatter group. I used process builder but it did not work, but it's working only the time i edit the status manually and save ,but not the time the field changed through approval process.
Can someone give an idea to work it?

Comment: I could able to make it using process builder but had to check the reevaluate workflow rule checkbox in approval process.